# unicode file name is some strange

Tags: python, django, unicode

I make a file upload view in django 1.8 and python 3.4.
I used encode method on filename to resolve the unicode issue. 
but the saved file name is stange :

```
[root@Moon 1]# ls
b'\xeb\xaa\xa9\xea\xb3\xb5'  b'\xeb\xaa\xa9\xea\xb3\xb5.jpg'  s1  s2
[root@Moon 1]#
```

how can i fix this?

my code :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' in request.FILES:
        filename = file._name
        try:
            fp = open(filename.encode('utf-8'), 'wb')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug(str(e))

        for chunk in file.chunks():
            fp.write(chunk)
        fp.close()
```

Comment: What is the content of the `filename` variable? Log it!

Comment: logger.debug('Filename:[%s]'%dilename.encode('utf-8')) --> Filename:[b'\xeb\xaa\xa9\xea\xb3\xb5.jpg']

Comment: It'is weird... If filename is already bytes string, encode() method will cause `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'` (python3.4) And what is your file names encoding? In Linux `echo $LANG` or `locale | grep LANG=`. Maybe it's not utf8?

Comment: already i have tried. export LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8

Comment: I don't think the code here is telling the whole story, as you have somehow picked up the `repr()` form of the string before using it as a filename. Where is `file` coming from? BTW you should **never** use user input like request.FILES content  as a local filename, this makes you vulnerable to directory traversal and webserver-special-filename attacks. Always use safe, programmatically-generated filenames for local file storage.

Comment: so I decide to use uuid.uuid4(). thanks. but I want to know why I cannot use unicode filename

Comment: `open(filename)` accepts unicode strings, so you don't need any `encode(...)` call there.